# MPA with Laravel and Vue ( hybrid approach )

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to understand when and how to mix the Laravel and Vue components in a web app.

- **MPA** where **each blade view** consists of a **Vue** component

Is it ok to have **server-side routing** and **each view** to **consist** of a **Vue** component ? Or in this case it would be better to make an **SPA** ? ( More specifically, here the question is whether there is a benefit of having server-side routing instead of client-side routing ? )

Taking as a reference **stack overflow**.

- When you click on a **Question** the page refreshes which means that a **GET** request is sent to the back-end and where a new html file is sent to front-end.
- When you create a **Question**, a new file is sent from the back-end and the page again reloads.

However, the content of the **Question** itself, seems to be dynamic because you can edit the **Question** or a **Reply**, but then again when you **save** the change, the **page reloads**.

- In this case, what is the benefit of communicating with the server with a **GET/POST** instead of making an **AJAX** call, taking into consideration that **the content of the page is rendered on the client-side with JS** which is **not SEO-friendly** ?

What are the **upsides** and **downsides** of this approach ?